# Obtaining relevant information from CARTO's format of the the_geom attribute

Tags: postgis, carto

I've just started using CARTO and wanted to join two files: the shape data and the data from the excel file. They have a common column, so I did the analysis and applied the inner join. Then I exported the data to a .csv file, opened it and wrinkled my nose at the the_geom column.

Geo data has the following form:
`0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000A000000BBE929E002B4004C0F7...[+100-150 chars of this sequence]...B84A40`.

It looks as if there was a pattern there, at least for first 30-40 chars - a lot of 0s, some Es (probably power)...

How can I extract information so that I'll be able to use it later for an analysis, for example: x/ycentroid, x/y max, area etc. (or refine what I've obtained)?

Comment: Cargo is based on PostgreSQL and PostGIS. Read about those and you will see that you do not really need to care about the binary format of geometries.

Comment: For starters, where are you taking this data after it leaves CARTO, and further to that, the centroid / max / area can all be done within CARTO itself using SQL and SQL Spatial functions (ST_Area(), etc.) - but maybe you're going out to QGIS to do some of this work?

Comment: Ok, so the first step should be working with data that contains the geometries, i.e applying functions like ST_Area, ST_xMax, ST_yMax etc. and THEN joining on the common attribute (after all refine data operations have been done)?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the comments, CARTO database is built on top of PostgreSQL and PostGIS. On the one hand, `the_geom` is CARTO's geometry column and that code is [a Well-Known Binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary). On the other hand, you can extract insights using PostGIS functions such as [`ST_AsText`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html), [`ST_Centroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) or [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html).